# How to run server-only code once on server startup in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, prisma, objection.js

I am trying to access my `User` objection.js model from `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`.

However, I need to run

```
import Knex from "knex";
import knexfile from "./knexfile";
import { Model } from "objection";

function setupDB() {
  const db = Knex(knexfile[process.env.NODE_ENV]);
  Model.knex(db);
}
```

on server startup.

When I do

```
  const users = await User.query();
```

inside `getStaticPaths`, I get `Error: no database connection available for a query. You need to bind the model class or the query to a knex instance.` error.

I tried running `setupDB()` inside `_app.js` with `typeof window === "undefined"` check, but just importing Knex and objection in `_app.js` throws an error.

Where should I run this? I really really want to avoid extending `server.js`.

(I should add there was [a discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15341) on next.js github, but not sure if there's a way to do it specific to Objection.js, or any recent development.