# How can I run the code only once when Next.js starts, instead of once for each request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, next.js

I am a beginner in Next.js and I want to use mongoose in Next.js, but I don't know where to connect to the database.
When I use Mongoose in Express, I connect to the database in `app.js`, so MongoDB only connects once at startup.

```js
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const userRouter = require('./routes/user_actions');
const app = express();

// Connect to MongoDB; this code will only run once when the app starts.
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/user');

app.use('/user', userRouter);
module.exports = app;
```

But in Next.js, I don't know where to connect to the database. I connect to the database in the `app/route.js`, but every request will connect to the database, which is not what I want. I wonder if it's possible to run the code once at startup in Next.js, like Express, instead of running the code once every time a request is made.

```js
// app/route.js
import {NextResponse} from 'next/server'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

// Connect to MongoDB; this code will run on every request.
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/user')

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const res = await request.json()
    console.log(request);
    console.log(res);
    return NextResponse.json({hello: 'world'})
}
```

I noticed a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793584/how-to-run-server-only-code-once-on-server-startup-in-next-js), but there is no answer.

What should I do in Next.js?

Thanks.

Comment: there's [this](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/nextjs-with-mongodb/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mongoose.connection.readyState`.

return:

- 0 = disconnected
- 1 = connected
- 2 = connecting
- 3 = disconnecting
- 99 = uninitialized

```js
if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 1) {
    console.log("is already connected");
    return;
}
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/user');
```